# Any event after all appenders are initialized?

Tags: .net, log4net

Is there any way to execute a custom action in my custom log4net appender after **all** other appenders are initialized?

Comment: I can't see any events in the code which would support this. Can you give a bit more information about what you want to do?

Comment: @stuartd, basically because I'm developing a complex appender for a socket connection, and I want to use another log4net logger to dump diagnostic info to a file.

Comment: Perhaps you could dynamically define configure that logger and its appenders within the initialisation of your custom logger?

Comment: @stuartd, maybe. Not sure how to do this without breaking something.